# Lucene/Examine query

Tags: lucene, umbraco

I'm using the following to run a lucene query:

```
var searchCriteria = searcher.CreateSearchCriteria(BooleanOperation.Or);

var query = searchCriteria.GroupedOr(new string[] { "title", "Name" }, searchTerm).Compile();
```

If the searchTerm = "Service Card For Vendors"

The query generated = (title:"services ? card vendors" Name:"services ? card vendors")

Why is "For" being replaced with "?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"for" is a stop word in the [StandardAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html#STOP_WORD_SET) in Lucene (see [StopFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/StopFilter.html)).  That is a word that is deemed common enough, and fairly useless for searching.  Mostly some conjunctions, pronouns and prepositions, I believe.  As such, it is cut out of both the indexed terms and search queries.

This prevents words like "for" "the" "it" etc. from playing havoc with scoring with tons of meaningless matches.